# Pyflink kafka topic consumption not working

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have this code consuming from confluent's kafka platform (pageviews) but for some reason, execution just hangs up and I can't get it to work. I am new to flink, my experience is mainly with spark streaming, so this is my learning process with flink.

Below you can find the python code and then the exception I found in the logs:

```py
from pyflink.datastream.connectors.kafka import KafkaSource, KafkaOffsetsInitializer
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.formats.json import JsonRowDeserializationSchema
from pyflink.common.watermark_strategy import WatermarkStrategy
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import FlinkKafkaConsumer
from pyflink.datastream.checkpoint_config import CheckpointingMode
import json
#########
schema_pageviews = Types.ROW_NAMED(
    [
        "schema",
        "payload",
    ],
    [
        Types.ROW_NAMED(
            ["type", "fields", "optional", "name"], 
            [
                Types.STRING(), Types.OBJECT_ARRAY(
                    Types.ROW_NAMED(["type", "optional", "field"], [Types.STRING(), Types.BOOLEAN(), Types.STRING()])
                ), Types.BOOLEAN(), Types.STRING(),
            ]
        ),
        Types.ROW_NAMED(
            [
                "viewtime",
                "userid",
                "pageid",
            ],
            [
                Types.LONG(),
                Types.STRING(),
                Types.STRING(),
            ]
        ),
    ],
)
stream_env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
stream_env.enable_checkpointing(1000)
stream_env.get_checkpoint_config().set_checkpointing_mode(CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE)
stream_env.get_checkpoint_config().set_checkpoint_storage_dir("file:///tmp")
value_deserializer = (
    JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder()
    .type_info(schema_pageviews)
    .build()
)
#kafka_source = KafkaSource.builder().set_bootstrap_servers("localhost:9092").set_group_id("repl-flink").set_topics("page_views").set_value_only_deserializer(value_deserializer).set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.earliest()).build()
kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
    topics='page_views',
    deserialization_schema=value_deserializer,
    properties={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'repl_flink'}
)
#page_views_stream = stream_env.from_source(kafka_source, WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), "pageviews-kafka")
page_views_stream = stream_env.add_source(kafka_consumer)
parsed_stream = page_views_stream.map(
    lambda obj: obj["payload"],
    Types.ROW_NAMED(
        [
            "viewtime",
            "userid",
            "pageid",
        ],
        [
            Types.LONG(),
            Types.STRING(),
            Types.STRING(),
        ]
    ),
)
parsed_stream.print()
stream_env.execute("app-name")
```

Exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/flink/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/bin/pyflink-udf-runner.sh": error=20, Not a directory
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4966) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:451) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:436) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:303) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:619) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/opt/flink/opt/python/pyflink.zip/pyflink/bin/pyflink-udf-runner.sh": error=20, Not a directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager.startProcess(ProcessManager.java:147) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager.startProcess(ProcessManager.java:122) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:104) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:252) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:231) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:451) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:436) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:303) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:619) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        ... 15 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Process for id does not exist: 4701-1
                at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:895) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager.stopProcess(ProcessManager.java:172) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:124) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:252) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:231) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:451) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:436) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:303) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:619) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.open(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:275) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalPythonFunctionOperator.java:57) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalDataStreamPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalDataStreamPythonFunctionOperator.java:85) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractExternalOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.java:117) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.process.ExternalPythonProcessOperator.open(ExternalPythonProcessOperator.java:64) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:107) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:726) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:702) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:669) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:935) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:904) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:728) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:550) ~[flink-dist-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=20, Not a directory
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager.startProcess(ProcessManager.java:147) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessManager.startProcess(ProcessManager.java:122) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.environment.ProcessEnvironmentFactory.createEnvironment(ProcessEnvironmentFactory.java:104) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:252) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$1.load(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:231) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3528) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2277) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2154) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2044) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3952) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.vendor.guava.v26_0_jre.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:451) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory$SimpleStageBundleFactory.<init>(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:436) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.beam.runners.fnexecution.control.DefaultJobBundleFactory.forStage(DefaultJobBundleFactory.java:303) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createStageBundleFactory(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:619) ~[flink-python-1.16.0.jar:1.16.0]
        ... 15 more
```

Message from kafka example:

```json
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "int64",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "viewtime"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "userid"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "pageid"
      }
    ],
    "optional": false,
    "name": "ksql.pageviews"
  },
  "payload": {
    "viewtime": 92871,
    "userid": "User_5",
    "pageid": "Page_31"
  }
}
```

Added dependencies to /lib:

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-kafka/1.16.0/flink-connector-kafka-1.16.0.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/3.3.1/kafka-clients-3.3.1.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-avro/1.16.0/flink-avro-1.16.0.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro/1.11.1/avro-1.11.1.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.14.1/jackson-core-2.14.1.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.14.1/jackson-databind-2.14.1.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.14.1/jackson-annotations-2.14.1.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-avro-confluent-registry/1.16.0/flink-avro-confluent-registry-1.16.0.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.12/3.3.1/kafka_2.12-3.3.1.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-base/1.16.0/flink-connector-base-1.16.0.jar
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-core/1.16.0/flink-core-1.16.0.jar
wget https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-jdbc/1.16.0/flink-connector-jdbc-1.16.0.jar
```

What does the exception mean? How can I debug this? So far I've been working on `pyflink-shell local`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the error is saying some directory within `/opt/flink/opt/python` does not exist... How did you install Flink? Can you run any example code they provide? Also, I don't think using wget is the best idea (you especially don't need the kafka_2.12 JAR)

Comment: Also, part of the path says `pyflink.zip` are You trying to run that inside the packed archive ?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I downloaded the binaries for 1.16 and just ran the REPL python shell, so basically just in "local" mode. I don't know if I should set env vars pointing to the python executable inside the active environment if that's the issue? What are your thoughts? Regarding the jars, I am just trying what I find in different places, I can get rid of unnecessary dependencies once it is ready to go to prod. But for now, downloading to /lib worked with missing dependencies errors.

Comment: @DominikWosiński I didn't do it explicitly, I don't know if REPL shell does this under the hood